# Bootstrap btn-group with disabled button & tooltip-wrapper - mess with btn order and rounded corners

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm unable to line up three buttons in boostrap button group.

1) I have btn-group and three buttons inside

2) Second and third button sometimes is disabled (logic for enable/disable is written inside knockout model, but it is not important here)

3) Second button has tooltip, so I created tooltip-wrapper for button, because disabled buttons cannot have tooltips (from Bootstrap documentation http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/:

> "Tooltips on disabled elements require wrapper elements To add a
>   tooltip to a disabled or .disabled element, put the element inside of
>   a  and apply the tooltip to that  instead."

4) I have added `container` for wrapper div as per deocumentation:

> Tooltips in button groups and input groups require special setting
>   When using tooltips on elements within a .btn-group or an
>   .input-group, you'll have to specify the option container: 'body'
>   (documented below) to avoid unwanted side effects (such as the element
>   growing wider and/or losing its rounded corners when the tooltip is
>   triggered).

Unfourtunately after this:

a) the order of third and second button changes.

b) three buttons doesn't look like a `btn-group`

I am unable to find a solution or an idea what to try. Changing button order doesn't help.

Here is html and JS fiddle link (http://jsfiddle.net/rRLB4/):

**P.S. Please, note that in JS Fiddle I have removed all spaces, enters and tabs in HTML and I do not TidyUp, otherwise there appears some empty spaces and `btn-group` is not lined up.**

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioEditModal" data-bind="click: triggerFileUpload, clickBubble: false" class="btn btn-primary">Import</button>
    <div class="tooltip-wrapper" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Enter data!">
        <button data-bind="click: trySave, clickBubble: false" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="">Save</button>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: showSaveAsDialog, clickBubble: false" disabled="">Save As</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `.tooltip-wrapper` to float left like buttons do in a button group and adjust the border radius of the button inside the wrapper. Something like this should work:

```css
.tooltip-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.tooltip-wrapper .btn {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.tooltip-wrapper:first-child .btn {
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.tooltip-wrapper:last-child .btn {
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
```

Here's your example updated: http://jsfiddle.net/sxqDt/12/

Answer (score 0):

```
//test you css code 
.tooltip{
       dislay:none !important;
 }

//if you use tooltip and this code copay paste your source css
 //when use tooltip

 .tooltip{
        position:fixed !important;

    }

 .tooltip-inner {
       padding:5px;
       color:#FFFFFF !important;
       font-size: 12px !important;
       max-width:250px !important;
       text-align:justify !important;
       word-break: break-all;
 }
```